# SQL: Map two table create a NEW one with new values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am working with CANADA education data, What I currently have is data based on Province level. I am trying to populate the data set for CMA level. So if a province 'A' contains 'n' number of CMAs then I have to map the educational data value of 'A' for all the 'n' CMAs.

what I did, for now, is, Loaded all the province-level data in one SQL table(image-2). Loaded CMA-PROVINCE data in another SQL table(image-1).

[image]

[image]

What I am trying to get is illustrated in the final picture below.

[image]

I have tried query like,

```
select t2.occ-code,t2.emp14, t2.emp15, t2.bachelor, t2.graduate, t2.province,t1.CMA, t2.type = cma
    from CMA_PROVINCE_Mapping t1, dataProvince t2
    where t1.PROVINCE = t2.provincee
```

I am getting error in update section of `t2.type = cma`

could anyone please help me with the mapping of these two tables for creating a new one.

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

don't need the t2.type = cma

```
select t2.occ-code,t2.emp14, t2.emp15, t2.bachelor, t2.graduate, t2.province,t1.CMA, t1.cma as type
        from CMA_PROVINCE_Mapping t1, dataProvince t2
        where t1.PROVINCE = t2.provincee
```